# Zxing QRCode MultiReader Android

Tags: android, bitmap, zxing

i'd like to read an image with 40 QRCodes.

I've tried to use it, but it doesn't returns anything. Can anyone help me with this issue ?

> ```
>   // To Handle Camera Result
>   if (intent != null && requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
>
>       Bitmap pictureObject = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");
>
>       int[] intArray = new int[pictureObject.getWidth()
>               * pictureObject.getHeight()];
>       // copy pixel data from the Bitmap into the 'intArray' array
>       pictureObject.getPixels(intArray, 0, pictureObject.getWidth(), 0,
>               0, pictureObject.getWidth(), pictureObject.getHeight());
>
>       LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(
>               pictureObject.getWidth(), pictureObject.getHeight(),
>               intArray);
>       BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
>
>       QRCodeMultiReader qrcode = new QRCodeMultiReader();
>
>       try {
>           Result[] result = qrcode.decodeMultiple(bitmap);
>
>           for (Result kp : result) {
>               tvScanResults.append(kp.getText());
>               tvScanResults.append("\n");
>           }
>
>       } catch (NotFoundException e) {
>           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       }
>
>   }
> ```